# If $S$ is a non empty set of real numbers and $X=\inf S$ show that for each $\varepsilon>0$ there is an $a \in S$ such that $a< X+\varepsilon$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I know that since $X = \inf S$ and $A \in S$ where $a \leqslant A 
X+\varepsilon$ is not a lower bound for $S$ but how do I complete this proof to say therefore there is an $a$ in $S$ such that $a<X+\varepsilon$?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that there is no $a \in S$ such that $a < X + \varepsilon$ for some $\varepsilon > 0$. Then $a \geqslant X + \varepsilon$ for every $a \in S$, so $X + \varepsilon > X$ is a lower bound for $S$. Why is this a contradiction?

Comment: I'm getting more confused

Comment: What is the definition of $\inf S$?

Comment: That is the lowest bound of S

Comment: @lalo2k1: no, the $\inf S$ is the *greatest* lower bound of $S$. Do you understand now?

Comment: As the above answer shows, if the proposition were false, S would have a lower bound that's greater than its greatest lower bound , which is like a mountain that's taller than the tallest mountain.